# Get word's line by using splitlines and Split

Tags: python, line, python-docx

I want to get the word in which line according to the text that user have enter.

Here is sample of code:

```
numLine =0

text = "How do you do? Am i \nsuppose to go somewhere?\nHere is the line i 
        don't know"

splittext= text.splitlines()
for i in splittext:
    numLine += 1
    if 'suppose' in i.split():
        print(str(numLine)+": "+i )
```

after text is insert and get the word line,

```
for i in splittext:
       numLine += 1
```

After that i try to split again if it is match with **'suppose'** word from splittext

```
        if 'suppose' in i.split():
        print(str(numLine)+": "+i )
```

the outcome of the print suppose to give

> ***2: suppose to go somewhere?***

But the terminal doesn't show the print. How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a more Pythonic way to solve your problem.

```
text = "How do you do? Am i \nsuppose to go somewhere?\nHere is the line i don't know"

for index, line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    if 'suppose' in line.split():
        print('{}: {}'.format(index + 1, line))
```

Explanation:

- Avoid creating extra variables such as `splittext` if you are only using them one time
- Use `enumerate()` when you want to iterate over a list and also do something with the counters
- Use string formatting rather than concatenation to print stuff nicely.

Comment: What if the the enter word is 'somewhere' not 'suppose'? I tried to run the code it doesn't print where the line is. The split line seem doesn't work.

It should be get the same result as: 2: suppose to go somewhere?

Comment: @Leow the `line.split()` is breaking the line into individual words based on whitespace. In your example, the question mark is not whitespace so the last string returned by `line.split()` would be `'somewhere?'`, which is not the same string as `'somewhere'`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `text2.splitlines()` instead of `text.splitlines()`?

Comment: this is supposed to be a comment